# Kubernetes RBAC - user has access to get pods but it says 'Unauthorized'

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, rbac

I have configured keycloak for Kubernetes RBAC.

- user having access to get pods

```
vagrant@haproxy:~/.kube$ kubectl auth can-i get pods --user=oidc
Warning: the server doesn't have a resource type 'pods'
yes
```

```
vagrant@haproxy:~/.kube$ kubectl get pods --user=oidc
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

my kubeconfig file for the user looks like below

```yaml
users:
- name: oidc
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - oidc-login
      - get-token
      - --oidc-issuer-url=https://test.example.com/auth/realms/kubernetes
      - --oidc-client-id=kubernetes
      - --oidc-client-secret=e479f74d-d9fd-415b-b1db-fd7946d3ad90
      - --username=test
      - --grant-type=authcode-keyboard
      command: kubectl
```

Is there anyway to get this to work?

Comment: have you done the kube API Server configuration for oidc?

Comment: Yes i have done it and even the cluster role and binding have been applied

Comment: can you share error logs from Kubernetes API Server..also have you installed Kubelogin?

Comment: ```E0410 09:15:17.480771       1 watcher.go:214] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
E0410 09:23:37.507506       1 watcher.go:214] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
E0410 09:38:52.523489       1 watcher.go:214] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
E0410 09:49:39.625155       1 watcher.go:214] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
E0410 09:58:04.676751       1 watcher.go:214] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision ```

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu These are the latest logs from kube-apiserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the ip address of the cluster. You might have to configure the DNS name if the ip address.